# PowerShell not printing to console

Tags: powershell, foreach, event-viewer

I have the below code which retrieves the last users to login after a certain number of days. I want to stop logins that I don't care about from appearing in the list, such as when it shows that "LOCAL SERVICE" or "NETWORK SERVICE" has logged in. I also designed it so that repeats will be excluded.

While trying to figure out why Powershell never thought `$Matches.AccountName` equaled "LOCAL SERVICE" or any of the other checks, I realized that powershell was refusing to print anything after this line

```
[void]($event.Message -match 'Account Name:\s{1,}(?<AccountName>.+)')
```

So I have three questions:

1. Why won't PowerShell print anything in this location?
2. What is wrong with my comparison that checks if AccountName is not equal to an account like "LOCAL SERVICE"? It always evaluates to false, thus allowing it to get added to the list
3. This one is a little off topic but is there a name for what I am doing with the whole `$result = foreach($event in $events)` thing? I don't quite understand how it works or how it knows what to set each index of `$result` equal to

```bsh
{
    $computer = $env:ComputerName
    if ($Days -eq $null) {
        $Days = Read-Host -prompt "Enter the number of days to go back"
    }
    $startDate = (Get-Date) - (New-TimeSpan -Day $Days)
    $events = Get-WinEvent -Computer $computer -FilterHashtable @{Logname='Security';ID=4672;StartTime=$startDate}

    [System.Collections.ArrayList]$arr = @() 
    $result = foreach ($event in $events) {
        [void]($event.Message -match 'Account Name:\s{1,}(?<AccountName>.+)')
        $Matches.AccountName.gettype()
        $Matches.AccountName
        "SYSTEM"
        $h = Read-Host -prompt "Stop here to see if anything printed"
        if ((-not ($arr.Contains($Matches.AccountName))) -and ($Matches.AccountName -ne "SYSTEM") -and ($Matches.AccountName -ne "LOCAL SERVICE") -and ($Matches.AccountName -ne "NETWORK SERVICE") -and ($Matches.AccountName -ne "Local Administrator")) {
            $arr.Add($Matches.AccountName) > $null;
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                AccountName = $Matches.AccountName;
                Time = $event.timeCreated
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What happens when you debug it in PowerShell ISE?

Comment: [1] your "print" items are going to the standard output stream ... and you are capturing that in `$result`. if you add something like `Write-Warning` you will see output. ///// [2] i haven't worked thru the test you use on this yet. [*blush*] ///// [3] the `foreach` loop sends its output to the standard output stream. the `$result = ` captures that output stream into a collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No print output
   you were capturing that to the `$Results` collection. anything on a line by itself is sent to the output stream ... and you were capturing it all.
2. Your comparison failed because your regex left a `CR` on the end of your `$Matches.AccountName`. I can't figure out how to fix the regex, so I simply used `.Trim()` on it. after that, things worked.

   However, you used an overly complex IF cascade. I switched to using `-notin $ExcludedAccountList` for a simpler test.
3. Sending stuff from the `foreach` to the `$Results` variable
   Anything that is sent to the output stream can be assigned to a `$Var`. In this case, the custom object was sent to the output stream ... and PoSh gathered all of that output, held it until the loop ended, and then stuffed the objects into the `$Var` on the left of the `=`.

---

Here is a slightly different way to get the info.

There is something wrong with your regex - it includes the line-ending `CR`. I was unable to fix that, so I simply used `.Trim()` on it.

your `if` cascade was too twisty, so I simplified that to test for `-notin` an excluded account list.

```
#Requires -RunAsAdministrator

$ExcludedAccountList = @(
    # I only have the "system" account listed
    #    commented this out so I could see something
    #'SYSTEM'
    'LOCAL SERVICE'
    'NETWORK SERVICE'
    'Local Administrator'
    )
$computer = $env:ComputerName

$Days = ''
if ($Days -eq '')
    {
    [int]$Days = Read-Host -prompt "Enter the number of days to go back"
    }
$startDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$Days)
$FilterHashtable = @{
    Logname = 'Security'
    ID = 4672
    StartTime = $startDate
    }
$EventList = Get-WinEvent -Computer $computer -FilterHashtable $FilterHashtable

$DupeCheck = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]::New()
# force the $Var to be an array even if only one item is returned
[array]$Results = foreach ($Event in $EventList)
    {
    $null = $event.Message -match 'Account Name:\s{1,}(?<AccountName>.+)'
    # get rid of trailing non-printing char [hex = "0d" - carriage return]
    $AccountName = $Matches.AccountName.Trim()

    # check if we already have that account name
    #    then exclude the unwanted account names
    if (-not $DupeCheck.Contains($AccountName) -and
        $AccountName -notin $ExcludedAccountList)
        {
        $DupeCheck.Add($AccountName)
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            AccountName = $AccountName
            Time = $event.timeCreated
            }
        }
    #>
    }

$Results
```

With the `$Days` set to 1, the `$Results` collection contains this:

```
AccountName Time
----------- ----
SYSTEM      2019-02-10 1:11:52 AM
```

Comment: The regular expression could be fixed by changing `(?<AccountName>.+)` to  `(?<AccountName>\S+)` (assuming that the account name itself doesn't contain whitespace characters). The reason why the trailing CR is in the match is because `.` matches any character except LF, meaning that with Windows-style line breaks (CR-LF) the CR is included in the match while the subsequent LF is not.

Comment: That was it! How were you able to determine that there was a CR on the end? And thank you for the useful information

Comment: you are welcome! [*grin*] ///// for the trailing character ... i could not make the items match - even tho they displayed as if identical. i have formed a habit of taking such things and feeding them into `Format-Hex` to see what is there. plus, once i had done that i finally tested the `.Length` of the match result. [*blush*] it gave 7 chars when `SYSTEM` only has 6 ...

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - thank you for the info [*grin*] ... i spent nearly 20 minutes trying various regex solutions and gave up. [*blush*]

Answer (score 0):

1. You write everything to the variable `$result`, hence nothing is printed to the console
2. `$arr` is an empty array, I don't see any reason to use an array here. Also the comparison is just so long that's difficult to find a flaw. You can do much much simpler, as I'll show in a second.
3. I don't know if there is a name, but what it does is writing all the output to a variable. If you do that, you should pay attention that only one type of object is stored. In your case you store a couple of string and then a `PSCustomObject`.

You can solve your problem much easier and readable by using the `-contains` or `-notcontains` operator, which checks whether or not an element exists in an array.
So, simply create an array of accounts which you want to filter out, check if the found account is part of the filter list and proceed. By doing so you also have no hassle to extend the list or even make the list part of the input of a function.

```
$FilteredAccounts = 'LOCAL SERVICE', 'NETWORK SERVICE'
$AccountRegEx = 'Account Name:\s{1,}(?<AccountName>.+)'

foreach ($Event in $Events) {
    [void]($Event.Message -match $AccountRegEx)
    if ($FilteredAccounts -notcontains $Matches.AccountName.Trim()) {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            AccountName = $Matches.AccountName
            Time = $Event.TimeCreated
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I did a direct copy and paste of your code and inserted `$result =` in front of the `foreach` but everything in `$FilteredAccounts` is still appearing in `$result`